# Logically what is the difference between method(xyz) and xyz.method()?

Tags: java, methods

Well I know that in first one xyz is passed in `method(xyz)` where xyz may be variable or String in java, further the method itself is defined by the user so this could be (or not) return depends upon the body which is written by the coder.

but now here comes the second one `xyz.method()`, has we know here xyz is object 
Are we passing xyz to this method just like first one. I mean what is going on inside there How this is working?

Please explain deeply you can take example from any of this or any of this.

1. `str.length();`
2. `str.toChar();`

Answer (score 1):

xyz.method() --> For this to work, method is to be exposed inside class XYZ by someone who wrote class XYZ. Since object itself is invoking method it knows about itself, there is nothing like object xyz is passed to method. But inside that method, xyz will be available as this, since xyz is the callee object.

method(xyz) --> method written in any class which expects object of type XYZ, this method not necessarily be a part of class XYZ. Here xyz is passed as a parameter to method and will not be available as this.

Answer (score 1):

`method(xyz)` means you are calling a method which is defined in current class.

`xyz.method()` means xyz is an object of some class (lets say `XYZ`), and you are calling a method which is defined in `XYZ` class.

This code snippet would be more helpful to you

```
class XYZ {
    public void method() {
        // some code here
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass {
    public void method1(XYZ xyz) {
        xyz.method();  // case two
    }

    public void mainMethod() {
        XYZ xyz = new XYZ();
        method1(xyz);   // case one
    }
}
```

**in first case :**

`xyz` is an argument to a method.

**in second case :**

we want to call a method which is defined in the class `XYZ`. but you can not access it directly like we did in first case. To access a method or a field that is defined in other class, we have to create an instance of that class( in our case `xyz`) and through that instance we can access those methods provided that the methods are not private.

Answer (score 1):

From object-orientation there is a logical difference. For example, if we call the method `kill` then `xyz.kill()` means the object xyz makes suicide and if we call the method `kill(xyz)` then someone kills xyz.

From technical there is a logical difference if the method is not static. The `xyz.method()` indicates that xyz must not be `null` (as far as the method is non-static). The `method(xyz)` indicates that xyz can be null and can be something else.

Furthermore there is no logical difference.